# Meaning and purpose of using datamodel in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

I just wanted to know the meaning and the situations where `DataModel` is used in JSF. I was not able to get a clear picture of it in the Java EE doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find the [linked javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) quite clear:

> **DataModel** is an abstraction around arbitrary data binding technologies
>   that can be used to adapt a variety of data sources for use by
>   JavaServer Faces components that support per-row processing for their
>   child components.

`DataModel` is used as a wrapper class to the data you want to display in a component supporting a *per-row processing*. This is typically the case of `h:dataTable`.

There is for instance `ResultSetDataModel` which is a subclass of `DataModel` and helps to display a SQL `ResultSet` in a `h:dataTable`. Without the `ResultSetDataModel` abstraction, you would have to transform the underlying `ResultSet` into a normal `Collection`. Thanks to `ResultSetDataModel` you don't have to do any transformation and you can *plug* the `ResultSet` directly in the JSF component.